# Dynamic memory allocation with arrays

Tags: arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I just started learning about dynamic arrays, so pardon me because this is likely a simple question.

From what I have learned, we use dynamic arrays so we can re-size an array while the program is running. After playing around of dynamic arrays, I got confused with this piece of code:

```
int nSize = 4;
int *pnArray = new int[nSize];
pnArray[10] = 3;

cout << pnArray[10] << endl;
```

I am confused because I defined the size of the array to be 4, but yet, I was able to assign the 10th index of the array with the number 3. Thus, this code outputs 3. Shouldn't I get an error?

I tried this with static arrays and ended up getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no array bounds check in C++ or C.  So you can easily go out of bounds of your arrays if you are not careful.  This is a common type of bug that occurs in C and C++, using memory outside the array bounds.  It can even go unnoticed for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some other languages there is no limitation for arrays in C/C++ and this is the source of some bugs. In your case you are accessing the memory location (your array's first element+10 location) which contains some random data and treat it as integer.